# @fontface not working for IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, font-face

I'm having a font-face the menu of my webpage. For all browsers is loading fine except for Internet Explorer. Here's what I'm using in my css:

```
@font-face{
   font-family: 'MyriadProSemibold';
   src: url('fonts/MyriadPro-Semibold.eot');
   src: local(MyriadPro-Semibold), url('fonts/MyriadPro-Semibold.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

Fonts are in a folder called fonts that is located in the same folder as the css file. I don't know how to debug this problem is anyone could point out what need to be done in order to make them work for IE9?

Comment: Try adding a TrueType version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you put the opentype file into [the font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator). Click on generate and download the `.zip` file you get.

Copy the fonts to your webhost and copy the CSS styles in the stylesheets.css into your stylesheet, you can change the name and you need to correct the paths to the new paths. Now it works on FireFox 3.5+, Chrome4+, Opera10+, iPad, iPhone, IE4+ (!) and Safari3.1+.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I saw font-face generator before but then I read "The generator is currently broken in Internet Explorer. We will fix it as soon as possible." on the webpage and I thought that the font-face wouldn't work in IE but after reading again I understood what they were talking about.

Answer (score 0):

This is the font-face format I use:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'MyriadProSemibold';
src: url('MyriadProSemibold.eot');src: url('MyriadProSemibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('MyriadProSemibold.woff') format('woff'),url('MyriadProSemibold.ttf') format('truetype');}
```